# Conceptual Misunderstanding of Hamilton-Jacobi Theory

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

I will use the example of one dimensional harmonic oscillator to explain my doubt.
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{q^2}{2}.$$
We allow,
$S=W-\alpha t.$

We get,

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial W}{\partial q}\right)^2+\frac{q^2}{2}=\alpha.$$

Which gives,

$$\frac{dW}{dq}=\sqrt{2\alpha-q^2}.$$

Now I can find out $S$ and find out $$\beta=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \alpha}$$

I have been asked to find a transformation which relates $x(t),p(t)$ to $x(0),p(0)$.

And the prescribed procedure is to look for another transformation which takes  $(\beta,\alpha) \to (x(0),p(0))$  then invert these equation to find the relation.

My question is my can't we set $\beta=p(0)$ and $\alpha = x(0)$ since they are arbitrary constants?

Why should I carry out the above procedure?